# get ajax request data from jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have this code in JSP

```
        Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        map.put("A", 10L);
        map.put("B", 20L);
        map.put("C", 30L);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.accumulateAll(map);

        System.out.println(json.toString());


        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Sunday");
        list.add("Monday");
        list.add("Tuesday");

        json.accumulate("weekdays", list);
        System.out.println(json.toString());
```

It prints

```
Info:   2
Info:   {"A":10,"B":20,"C":30}
Info:   {"A":10,"B":20,"C":30,"weekdays":["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday"]}
```

In netbeans's ouput

my ajax is

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../include/residents.jsp',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        id: id,
    },
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function(data) {}
}).done(function() {
});
```

How can I show those ouput data in ajax success or done functions?

Comment: append the elements on the page

Comment: when i check the XHR > Response I dont see anything so i assume that the ouput is not returned to ajax it is only in the url page. How can i send it to the ajax ? @madalinivascu i mean how to return it?i tried `return json.toString();` but i get error

Comment: @madalinivascu also tried `response.getOutputStream().print( json.toString() );` but getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`

Comment: you should see some text in the response body, because you are printing it to the page

Comment: @madalinivascu that is what i am expecting also but the `Response Tab` is clean as well as the `Preview Tab`.. is `System.out.println(json.toString());` enough or i need to put it another way?

Comment: why are you printing the json multiple times?

Comment: how do you know what it prints if you do a post request?

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting you json once

```
System.out.print(json);
System.out.flush();
```

in ajax use a combination of `append` and `each` to loop the  weekdays

Comment: i use `out.println(jsonMap.toString());` it shows now in Preview problem is the format is wrong not json output is like `{
 fname = John, lname = Smith
}` so the `jsonMap.put( "lname", lname );
                    jsonMap.put( "fname", fname );` is wrong any idea how to make it put data like json out put?

Comment: got it i used `JSONObject json = new JSONObject();` then `json.put( "lname", lname );
                    json.put( "fname", fname );` thanks for ideas :)\